# establish a relationship among a table with many different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database

i have a table (piovt table) that links the invoice id and the service id, but the service id does not come from one table but comes from different tables. here is an example of that.

[image: database structure]

i tried use polymorphic relations but i only get the last recored not all recoreds related to the invoice

so how to get the services from invoice table?

Comment: Share your relationship methods in the model please

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Has One Through relationship.

Laravel documentation states "The "has-one-through" relationship defines a one-to-one relationship with another model. However, this relationship indicates that the declaring model can be matched with one instance of another model by proceeding through a third model."

You can read more and get code examples here

[Laravel has one through relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through)